# Check that: it is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

My question is:
Let $f \in C^{1} [0,1]$ & let $f'$ denote its derivative. Define: $|| f ||_{1} = ( \int_{0}^{1} (|f(t)|^{2} + |f'(t)|^{2})dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$We are to show that: $||f||_{1}$ defines a norm on $ C^{1} [0,1]$.

**My Attempt**:

Clearly, Positivity, Non-degeneracy, Homogeneity has been checked easily. Now to prove the triangle inequality, It is enough to show that: $|| f+g ||_{1}^{2} \le (||f||_{1} + ||g||_{1})^{2}.$ Now, to show that, I have expanded both side & found that it is enough to show that: $(\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|.|g(t)|dt + \int_{0}^{1} |f'(t)|.|g'(t)|dt) \le ( \int_{0}^{1}(|f(t)|^{2}+|f'(t)|^{2})dt)^{\frac {1}{2}}.( \int_{0}^{1}(|g(t)|^{2}+|g'(t)|^{2})dt)^{\frac {1}{2}}.$

But here I have got stucked!! Thereafter for the R.H.S. I have firstly used Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality's integral form & then used Root-mean-squared is greater than Arithmetic Mean.But till now, cannot get the result!! Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Prove that
$$\langle f/g\rangle=\int_0^1 \left(f(t)g(t)+f'(t)g'(t)\right)dt$$
is an inner product.

Comment: @ .. Sami Ben Romdhane, Yes! Your statement is true! & We know that from inner product we will get a norm.. But, I cannot patch this result with whatever I have got now!!

Comment: To prove manualy the triangle inequality you should repeat the proof of this inequality using the Cauchy-Shwarz inequality in this particular case.

Comment: @ ..  Sami Ben Romdhane : Sorry, are you suggesting to re[eat the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz in this particular cas?? I didn't get you!! Please show me the solution!!